# Upload value to mysql from multiple .txt depending on one txt file

Tags: php

I have a dropdown menu like this:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   
   $filename = 'abo.txt';
   $eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
   ?>
    <body>
        <div id="page-wrap" class="theme-pink">
            <select select style="width:100%" id="prisplan" name="prisplan" required>
                <option selected value="">Choose prisplan</option>
                <?php foreach($eachlines as $lines){ //add php code here
               echo "<option value='".$lines."'>$lines</option>";
                }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body><br>
```

The `abo.txt` file contains circa 100 rows that looks like this:

```
Apple
Lemon
Pear
Banana
... and so on
```

I have another text document in the same directory named `value.txt` with the same amount of rows, that looks like this (none of the numbers has desimals):

```
1
4
8
1
... and so on
```

So the first row in `abo.txt` has value first row in `value.txt`. So Apple  = 1, Lemon = 4, and so on.

I am storing this value in a database, and in my `insert.php` file, I get the value from the option select like this: `$prisplan = $_POST['prisplan'];`. So if the option select selected value from line 45 in `abo.txt`, it should also store value from the same line in `value.php`, but I have no idea how to proceed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After pressing the submit button. Try something like this:

```
<?php
$prisplan = $_POST['prisplan'];
echo $prisplan . '<br>'; 

// abo file
$filename = 'abo.txt';
$eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$indexIs = array_search($prisplan, $eachlines);

// value file
$filename = 'value.txt';
$eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$valueIs = $eachlines[$indexIs];
echo $valueIs . '<br> ';
?>
```

Comment: Yes, in that way. The script is made to act grabbing the $_POST value and process it.